# mvn versions:update-parent without tycho extension

Tags: maven, tycho, maven-extension

How can you easily disable the tycho extension if it is not needed (eg at versions:update-parent)?

I have a few dozen eclipse-plugin projects and resolve the target platform slows down the process unbearable.

Answer (score 0):

"passing he argument "-Dtycho.mode=maven" disables tycho resolution."

http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/tycho-user/msg04864.html